# Facebook $facebook->getUser() is not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

We are trying to get user information from getUser() method of facebook using php sdk (3.1.1) but it returns 0. what would be the cause?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));
$facebook->getUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest SDK is v.3.2.2 https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/ you should use that instead and also be using a login handling logic with `getLoginUrl()`